# Thevenin calculation

Tags: dc, thevenin

I know this is "noob-ish",but where do you actually put in the Thevenin calculation. Particularly I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDfFM.jpg) circuit and I know the Thevenin will be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25UVO.jpg), my question is why is R4 on the top(I know why it is R3 + R4 down)?

Comment: R3 and R4 together form a voltage divider. Hense the Vth voltage is the voltage drop across R4. Vth = VR4 = I*R4, And the current I = V1/(R3 + R4) so putting this together we have Vth = V1/(R3 + R4) * R4 = V1* R4/(R3 + R4)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Thevenin voltage is the open-circuit voltage you "see" from the load side, after you remove the load. If you wanna calculate the thevenin voltage seen from Q2's base, then remove it.You can see that it is nothing but the voltage across the R4. The R4 and R3 form simple voltage divider here. Hence,
$$V_{th} = V_1*R4/(R_3+R_4)$$

Comment: Ok i think i get it, but, couldn't it also be the voltage across R3? What makes it have to go through R4?

Comment: No, thevenins voltage appear between R4 and ground, when you see from the base and GND of Q2. Not between R3 and R4, nor between R3 and GND.

Comment: Thank you! I tought about that but i have those problems with diodes, [this](https://imgur.com/a/xz6zY) one , here the R2 it's not at mass, why is it on the upper side of the ratio?

Comment: Because it has to be the voltage across R2. There R2 and R1 forms a voltage divider. when Rd is removed.

Comment: One last thing, i have [this](https://imgur.com/a/Z2r1L) circuit and i have to find if the amplitude on the diode "V a,max" meets the small signal criteria.I can see how the "Th2" Thevenin works, but V a,max is also a Thevenin, how will I reach that formula , because i have rd||R4 and a Thevenin instead of R1 and R2, won't that make it a simple circuit in wich i could do Ohm?

Comment: Wouldn't it look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/dvU4V)?

Comment: Yea ........ :-)